# Android: Loading groupviews dynamically

Tags: android, menu, view, dynamic

I am trying to figure out how to load different groupviews dynamically.
I am creating application that will have menu with 4 categories and each category will have several sub-menu items. I have created four LinearLayouts with sub-menu buttons inside (they are separate xml files).
Now I want to display appropriate sub-menu in my main view every time the category is changed.

So far I have:
HorizontalScrollView sView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.CustomScrollView);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.category1_menu_layout);
sView.removeAllViews();
sView.addView(ll);

However this doesn't work because the ll for some reason is null(category1_menu_layout is the id of the LinearLayout inside the category1_menu.xml)

Do you have any ideas why that doesn't work? Maybe there is another ways of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have any ideas why that doesn't work?

Because you do not have a widget whose ID is `@+id/category1_menu_layout` presently defined in your activity.

> Maybe there is another ways of doing this?

Use a `ListView`. Or use an `ExpandableListView`. Or inflate the categories using `getLayoutInflater()`. Or create the categories in Java code.